# Decrypt code with sha1 with salt appended before

Tags: encryption, hash, sha1

I have a key to be decrypted shown here dc6f0dbebfc5747330deeedfbd8475568a740d0a. The following key has salt value prefixed before the key. The salt value is 80808080. How can i decrypt this.

Comment: SHA is a hashing also, not an encryption algo. It is not possible to recover the original text. Validations are done by using the salt, _with the same original text_, to produce the same hash.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming (and hashes are indeed one way, and the protocol is not written down)

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are not meant to be broken but you can use a tool like [this](https://www.dcode.fr/sha1-hash) to crack it (If you're lucky). This hash is for the string 'azerty'

Answer (score 0):

Hashes are not decrypted. In their regular usage as password hashes, you can validate an entered password using the hash but you can't find the password given the hash, because the hash function isn't reversible. The exception is brute force password cracking which works for sufficiently simple passwords only.